# django.core.exceptions.ValidationError: ['“” value has an invalid date format. It must be in YYYY-MM-DD format.'] problem

Tags: django

In 'models.py' i have this fields.

```
first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=True)
last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=True)
date_of_brith = models.DateField(default='YYYY-MM-DD', null=True)
email = models.EmailField(max_length=50, null=True)
```

When i try to migrate. I get this error. I tryed to delete also the field and I still have the same error

django.core.exceptions.ValidationError: ['“” value has an invalid date format. It must be in YYYY-MM-DD format.']

Answer (score 0):

instead of this:

```
date_of_brith = models.DateField(default='YYYY-MM-DD', null=True)
```

Try this:

```
import datetime
date_of_brith = models.DateField(default=datetime.date.today)
```

Note: it will display today's date as default

Do migrations manually using below command:

```
python manage.py makemigrations appname

python manage.py sqlmigrate appname 0001 #Value like this will generate automatically after makemigrations

python manage.py migrate
```

Comment: Hello. Anything I write I get the same error over and over again when i do migrate

Comment: how you did migrate?

Comment: python manage.py makemigrations

Comment: python manage.py migrate

Comment: So you are not doing manually that's why you got error. i'm updating my answer

Comment: Same error.  I don't know what to do..

Comment: Do one thing, delete all migration folders and re-migrate using above commands as mentioned in answer